# Annotate scatterplot from a pandas dataframe

Tags: matplotlib, pandas

I am using pandas and matplotlib to visualize this dataframe

```
    HDD  EnergyPerSquareMeter   Year
0    3333.6  23.11   1997
1    3349.6  24.30   1998
2    3319.5  24.78   1999
3    3059.1  22.01   2000
4    3287.5  24.17   2001
5    3054.9  20.01   2002
6    3330.0  21.25   2003
7    3307.3  19.22   2004
8    3401.4  18.31   2005
9    3261.6  20.40   2006
10   3212.8  15.34   2008
11   3231.2  15.95   2009
12   3570.1  15.79   2010
13   2995.3  13.88   2011
```

And I would like to plot EnergyPerSquareMeter as scatterplot (with the x-axis=HDD) and annotate the points with the year.

I did this:

```
ax =EnergyvsHDD.plot(x='HDD', y='EnergyPerSquareMeter', marker="o" , linestyle='None', figsize=(12,8))
for i, txt in enumerate(EnergyvsHDD['Year']):
    ax.annotate(txt, (x[i],y[i]), size=10, xytext=(0,0), ha='right', textcoords='offset points')
```

The outcome is:

[image]

The annotated text of the years doesn´t appear near the points. What am I doing wrong?

UPDATED

Using this code:

```
def label_point_orig(x, y, val, ax):
    a = pd.concat({'x': x, 'y': y, 'val': val}, axis=1)
    print a
    for i, point in a.iterrows():
        ax.text(point['x'], point['y'], str(point['val']))
```

And then:

```
ax = EnergyvsHDD.set_index('HDD')['EnergyPerSquareMeter'].plot(style='o')
label_point_orig(EnergyvsHDD.HDD, EnergyvsHDD.EnergyPerSquareMeter, EnergyvsHDD.Year, ax)
draw()
```

The points don't appear in the proper place:

[image]

Although using this code it works:

```
plt.scatter(list(EnergyvsHDD.HDD), list(EnergyvsHDD.EnergyPerSquareMeter))
label_point_orig(EnergyvsHDD.HDD, EnergyvsHDD.EnergyPerSquareMeter, EnergyvsHDD.Year, plt)
draw()
```

[image]

Does anybody know why?

Comment: I've used this code to generate labels, however, it seems that it shows floating point values even my values are type of integer. Do you have the same problem?